# How to automatically update a JSP page

Tags: ajax, jsp, page-refresh

I need to automatically refresh a div in JSP (call database).

My database is updated every second (GPS data).

Answer (score 0):

You can either refresh the whole page (See [Refresh a page using javascript or html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294842/how-to-refresh-a-page-using-javascript)) or, better, use Ajax call to the server and just update the needed div.