# How to refresh page, after async function is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript code, and I need to refresh the current page after its succesful

shouldnt be that hard?

```
function UpdateToCompleted(itemId) {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Bill Cycles');
        this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemId);
        oListItem.set_item('StatusColumn', 'Completed');
        oListItem.update();
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.StatusCompletedSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.StatusCompletedFailed));
    }

    function StatusCompletedSucceeded() {
        alert('Item updated!');
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean refresh the data on the page, or reload the page completely?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to refresh a page using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294842/how-to-refresh-a-page-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

or this:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

The parameter specifies whether or not to force the page to be loaded from the server.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
function StatusCompletedSucceeded() {
        window.location.reload();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location.reload();
```

Should do it