# using meta tag once button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have a Button setup and I am wondering how I would run the meta only once the button is pressed.

Here is the button code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="waitingDialog.show();setTimeout(function () {waitingDialog.hide();}, 900000);">
Show dialog 
</button>
```

and I want to run this meta once the button is pressed:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.example.com"/>
```

The onclick function basically opens a popup that tells the user that the page is loading

Thanks

-Tom

Comment: I'm not sure a meta tag is the right direction to go with this. You could check out this post for some other ideas though :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294842/refresh-a-page-using-javascript-or-html Javscript is littered with ways to load a page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but after looking at that, it just does the same thing, and re directs without the button being pushed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code help you :

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div {
            background-color: yellow;
            color: red;
            width: 80px;
            height: 20px;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="load">Loading...</div>
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
         Show dialog 
        </button>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").click(function(){
                    $("#load").fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
                    $('head').append('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.example.com"/>');
                })
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, so while it is waiting, how would I make this show, this is the code: waitingDialog.show(); This is a JS thing

Answer (score 0):

However there are several ways to redirect to a new page using javaScript and jquery, you can force the page to redirect using meta tag by adding a meta tag through jquery:

```
$('head').append('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.example.com"/>');
```

This code should be inside your setTimeout function. As the code is too long I suggest to put it in a separate function and call it onClick.

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="mydialog()">Show dialog</button>
    <scrtipt type="text-javascript">
       function mydialog(){
            waitingDialog.show();
           $('head').append('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.example.com"/>');
            setTimeout(function () {
               waitingDialog.hide(); 
            }, 900000);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: So should this work?                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="waitingDialog.show();setTimeout(function () {waitingDialog.hide();}, 900000);">Home page
                      <script type="text/javascript">
                      setTimeout(function(){
                      $('head').append('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.example.com"/>');
                      }, 3000);
                      </script>

Comment: No. I have updated the answer. However I don't know what is that 900000 really? do you want to wait 900 seconds before redirecting?!

Comment: No, that is to ensure that a popup stays up incase of slow internet connection

Comment: Ok. So I put the **redirect meta** outside of setTimeout and it should work as you need.

Comment: I am still having the problem of it automatically redirecting, without the button being pushed, and the waitingDialog box doesn't show up anymore