# In JavaScript, trying to reload the page when a condition is met

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a game in JavaScript and when the user wins/loses I am prompted them if they would like to play again.

Instead of reseting all the vars, is there a way to just reload the page?

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294842/refresh-a-page-using-javascript-or-html.

Comment: For better usability i prefer to reset your form (if exists and possible) `document.getElementById("myForm").reset();` instead of reloading a page

Comment: So with the function of reload is there anyway to keep some vars the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use `reload`:

```
location.reload();
```

You can also load other documents with the `replace` method:

```
location.replace("/other_page.html")
```

Comment: So with the function of reload is there anyway to keep some vars the same?

Comment: @JustinBesteman Yes, use GET when reloading the page (use`replace` to the same page with the variables in the URL as GET variables), and load them back (if they exist) when loading up using this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/ . URL with GET looks like `you.url.(or.localhost)?var1=value1&var2=value2&...varn=valuen`

Comment: Can you go into more detail with this?

Comment: Reload using `replace("?score_u1=" + score_u1 + "&score_u2=" + score_u2)` and so on. Then, on the beginning of your code, check if `score_u1` is in the GET variables (using the code from the link above). If it is, load the given value (parse as int the string provided) and use it.

Answer (score 2):

`location.reload();` reloads the current document.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location.reload()`.

It works like refresh button