# Sharepoint 365 (online) reload webpart

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have a EditForm custom page with two webparts connected between them. The first one is a form and the second is list of tasks related to the form item.
I have a custom "New Task" button with the following code:

```
InitClickBtn();

//******** Basic Dialog Starts Here ***********/
    function openBasicDialog(tUrl, tTitle) {
        var options = {
            url: tUrl,
            title: tTitle
        };
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }
    //******** Basic Dialog Ends Here ***********/

    //******** Get URL Params - Start ***********/
    var QueryString = function () {
        // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
        // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
        var query_string = {};
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split("&");
        for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split("=");
            // If first entry with this name
            if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
                query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
                // If second entry with this name
            } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
                var arr = [ 
query_string[pair[0]],decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) ];
                query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
                // If third or later entry with this name
            } else {
                query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
            }
        } 
        return query_string;
    }();

    //******** Get URL Params - End ***********/    

    function InitClickBtn() {
        $(".btn").on("click",function(){
            var _url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
"/Lists/Tasks%20List/NewForm.aspx?id=" + QueryString.ID;
            openBasicDialog(_url, "New Task Assignment");
        });
    };
```

It works very good, but, what when I create a new task in dialog window and save it, the dialog window is closed, the webpart on the parent page is not reloaded following the save, so I don't see the task in the list untill the page is refreshed. When I press on edit button next to he task item the window opens i can update the item and then the webpart is reloaded and changes can imidiately be seen without refreshing the parent page.

Thanks in advance,

Alen

Answer (score 0):

You can add page refresh script to reload the page after your code does its job.

```
window.location.reload()
```

or

```
window.location.href=window.location.href
```

Ref : [Refresh a page using javascript or html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294842/refresh-a-page-using-javascript-or-html)

Comment: This is not working. It refreshes all the page and I loose the changes that were not previously saved. Thats the reason i need to refresh only the webpart.