# Javascript - refresh current tab with http response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am sending `http` request to my server and the response is a html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/jQUERYUI.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id = "first">
data : someData
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the current page will refresh with the response data so I tried:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function(response) {
      var win = window.open(window.location.href, '_blank');
      $(win.document.body).html(response.data)
  }, function(error) {

  });
```

And some of the 535 ways to reload page using js [535-ways-to-reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294842/refresh-a-page-using-javascript-or-html).
Still I was not able to reload the current page with the response html.

Also I want the the url of the current page won't change.
`angularjs` ways to do so will be great as well.

Thanks for ant help.

Comment: why is your server returning HTML ?

Comment: You probably should be storing the response data in a property of your controller and using ng-bind-html or maybe just ng-bind-html to bind an element to your controller function.

Comment: @Nicolas - it is created after a long completion process.

Comment: You should return raw data (in JSON / XML) and let your front-end interpret it.

Comment: I know but there is a lot of business logic and more reasons why we chose that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. When you receive the html from the server, you rewrite the document with it. But do not redirect to itself, otherwise the browser rewrites once again.

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function(response) {
      $(win.document.body).html(response.data)
  }, function(error) {

  });
```

Answer (score 2):

why don't you route it to `/someUrl` in a main div inside body?

Comment: You could also change the view, which won't change the urll

Comment: can you post a example - I dont want to usr `routeProvider` if that is what you mean, and the html is created dynamically so there is no 'html' file on the server.

Comment: to route, no need to have a html file in server. if a api is returning, then also it will work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to refresh the page, just override the HTML of the current page with JavaScript:

```
window.document.body.parentNode.innerHTML = response.data;
```

As your result has HTML tags already, you might want to strip those first:

```
response.data.replace(/<?\/html>/, '');
```