# Refresh command not present in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am a beginner to selenium and have downloaded and installed the IDE. I'm following some tutorials and although at least some commands work (I can go to google and search for something), for some reason not all commands are available in the IDE and I have no idea why.

I tried restarting my browser and my computer, but the refresh command isn't part of the dropdown. I also tried manually typing Refresh as a command in the ide, but I get an error message saying: Unknown command refresh. See image
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P9Ol.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [executeScript](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands#execute-script) command and use Javascript to refresh the page.
There are multiple ways of using JS Refresh detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7632005/7964299)